# Check a string for a substring in a batch file (Windows)?

Tags: regex, string, batch-file

Let's say I have some text in a variable called $1. Now I want to check if that $1 contains a certain string. If it contains a certain string I want to print a message. The printing is not the problem, the problem is the check.  Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: start here: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: Thanks! Doesnt really help ... I was hoping there is somethiing easier. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way in my opinion is this :

```
set YourString=This is a test

If NOT "%YourString%"=="%YourString:test=%" (
    echo Yes
) else (
    echo No
)
```

Basiclly the string after ':' is the string you are looking for and you are using not infront of the if because %string:****% will remove the **** from the string making them not equal.

Comment: As with [Igor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8757658/1012053), this test ignores case. Also, it is safer to use delayed expansion. Finally, it cannot be used if the substring contains `=`.

Comment: I want to provide an example what is happening here. If you have  a string `abc` and you want to check for a substring `b` the expression is `not "abc"=="abc:b"` and it's evaluated as `not "abc"=="ac"` (true). If we search for `x` in the same string we have `not "abc"=="abc"`(false) because `abc:x` won't replace any symbol.

Answer (score 12):

The SET search and replace trick works in many cases, but it does not support case sensitive or regular expression searches.

If you need a case sensitive search or limited regular expression support, you can use FINDSTR.

To avoid complications of escaping special characters, it is best if the search string is in a variable and both search and target are accessed via delayed expansion.

You can pipe $1 into the FINDSTR command with the ECHO command. Use `ECHO(` in case $1 is undefined, and be careful not to add extra spaces. `ECHO !$1!` will echo `ECHO is off.` (or on) if $1 is undefined, whereas `ECHO(!$1!` will echo a blank line if undefined.

FINDSTR will echo $1 if it finds the search string - you don't want that so you redirect output to nul. FINDSTR sets ERRORLEVEL to 0 if the search string is found, and 1 if it is not found. That is what is used to check if the string was found. The `&&` and `||` is a convenient syntax to use to test for match (ERRORLEVEL 0) or no match (ERRORLEVEL not 0)

The regular expression support is rudimentary, but still useful.

See FINDSTR /? for more info.

This regular expression example will search $1 for "BEGIN" at start of string, "MID" anywhere in middle, and "END" at end. The search is case sensitive by default.

```
set "search=^BEGIN.*MID.*END$"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo(!$1!|findstr /r /c:"!search!" >nul && (
  echo FOUND
  rem any commands can go here
) || (
  echo NOT FOUND
  rem any commands can go here
)
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. Although I wish that it was a bit organized of what does what. Know you explained it in but hard to understand.

Comment: Good answer, with the advantage that the search string can be set as a variable (i.e. `set "search=something"`, which you can't do with the substitution trick. An improvement would be to demonstrate searches for "at start only", "at end only" (neither of which I could get working, but which are less useful) and "case-insensitive" (which just requires the `/i` switch)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know cmd.exe has no built-in function which answers your question directly. But it *does* support replace operation. So the trick is: in your $1 replace the substring you need to test the presence of with an empty string, then check if $1 has changed. If it has then it *did* contain the substring (otherwise the replace operation would have had nothing to replace in the first place!). See the code below:

```
set longString=the variable contating (or not containing) some text

@rem replace xxxxxx with the string you are looking for
set tempStr=%longString:xxxxxx=%

if "%longString%"=="%tempStr%" goto notFound
echo Substring found!
goto end

:notFound
echo Substring not found

:end
```

Comment: Note - this type of search is case insensitive. Also can have problems with special characters. It is more robust when using delayed expansion for both the search/replace and the equality check. But search string cannot contain `=` char, and search string cannot start with `~` or `*`.

Comment: @dbenham: Absolutely fair remark, my solution is far from perfect (as is cmd syntax, though).