# Use regexp in .BAT to find substring

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

How can I check contains of substring in string variable of batch file?

for example:

```
set var1=foobarfoo

set regexp=.*bar.*

if [check var1 by regexp] echo "YES"
```

In my case, it's must be only check by regular expression and only in .bat file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjusting the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758579/2899559) give

```
@echo off
set var1=foobarfoo
set "regexp=.*bar.*"
echo %var1%
echo %regexp%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo(%var1%|findstr /r /c:"%regexp%" >nul && (
    echo FOUND
    rem any commands can go here
) || (
    echo NOT FOUND
    rem any commands can go here
)
```

Comment: Thx, good work example. Now I try convert it for my "real" case.