# How do I extract only part of a file name in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

Say I have a file name that is really long, like: `asdfiiemqpovnweujweurvqvqv.txt`

and I want `sdfiiem`, which is the second character to the eighth character. How would I check if my file name has that string of characters in that specific location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get a substring from an environment variable, so the following will work:

```
@echo off
set filename=%1
echo %filename:~1,7%
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check a string for a substring in a batch file (Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756804/check-a-string-for-a-substring-in-a-batch-file-windows)

Here is what I could find that has already been posted.

```
set YourString=asdfiiemqpovnweujweurvqvqv.txt

If NOT "%YourString%"=="%YourString:sdfiiem=%" (
    echo Yes
) else (
    echo No
)
```