# Checking a string for substring with 2 variables with batch in Windows?

Tags: string, batch-file, substring, concatenation

I'm following the answer in [Check a string for a substring in a batch file (Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756804/check-a-string-for-a-substring-in-a-batch-file-windows). [Wald's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764201),

```
set YourString=This is a test

If NOT "%YourString%"=="%YourString:test=%" (
    echo Yes
) else (
    echo No
)
```

does kinda work. However, I'm having trouble changing test= into a variable of my own. I followed another [answer of concatenating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27116608) 2 variables but none of them seemed to work. **Basically, I want to check if '*YourString*' contains '*OtherString*' without a super long amount of code.**

Here is the code I have right now

```
set YourString=This is a test
set OtherString=test

If NOT "%YourString%"=="%YourString:%%=%" (
    echo Yes
echo !YourString%OtherString%=!
pause
) else (
    echo No
echo "%YourString:test=%"
pause
)
```

Comment: Interesting that you know to use delayed expansion on the `echo !YourString%OtherString%=!` line (that I suspect is supposed to be `echo !YourString:%OtherString%=!` but you aren't using it in the `if` statement as `!YourString:%OtherString%=!`